# How to combine low and high frequencies of two images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

I would like to combine two images A and B in the following way:

1) I want to take a Fourier transform of both of them

2) For image A I want to apply a weighted filter, which gives more emphasis for low 
frequencies

3) For image B I want to apply a weighted filter, which gives more emphasis for high frequencies

4) I want to combine these frequencies and take the inverse Fourier transform

Can someone give me any guidelines where I should start (which functions etc.) to do this in Matlab? =) I'm kinda learning about Fourier transform and I want to play around with images. I was hoping if someone could give an example of code how this could be done etc.

Thank you for any help! =)

Comment: Start by checking out FFT2 and IFFT2: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft2.html

Comment: `fftshift` is also useful.

Comment: another nice experiment you can do is take phase info from one image and amplitude info from second image and combine them ;-) gives very nice results. See question 8 [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/courses/2013_2/ex1/ex1.pdf)

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answers! I will give them a try :)

Comment: But how do I do the filtering and combining? :) To combine do I only need to take the sum of the two filtered fourier transforms?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by more weight to low frequency components?

Comment: I mean that in image A all the low frequencies will be multiplied with a very high number and high frequencies with a very small number so that all the low frequencies in image A will have more emphasis and high frequencies will have low emphasis. I want to combine the low frequencies of image A and high frequencies of image B. I'm new at this so bear with me ;) Did that clarify?

Comment: You don't actually need to go to the frequency domain to do this - you could just do spatial domain filtering and then combine (add) the filtered images.

Comment: @Paul R Thank you for your answer! Could you perhaps give a short code snippet how I would do this in Matlab? =)

Comment: No problem with that. Why don't you just say add the maximum of your high frequency components to lower frequency components?

Comment: I don't know :D I'm not so familiar with Fourier transform yet so I'm not familiar with the terminology yet etc. ;D I'm an amateur trying to learn these things by doing an experiment :)

Comment: IF you are an amateur trying to learn, then START LEARNING! The way to learn these things is by playing around in MATLAB, NOT by asking someone else to hand feed you answers. Try something. See what happens. Read the help. You will learn far more by doing this than by getting hand fed a solution.

Comment: @woodchips One professor once said to me that it saves a lot of needless effort and time, if you just ask someone who already knows the subject bottom to top rather than trying to search the answer your looking for and spending hours finding it. I'm just trying to optimize :)

Comment: You are just trying to be lazy. Admit it. You will only get a small piece of the puzzle, and then the next time you have a simple question that you should learn yourself, your recourse will be to plead for help again. Sit down and START DOING! Make an effort.

Comment: @woodchips The truth is, I just wanted to try my luck if someone could've given me an example on how to do this, because I was curious. I thought I could save time, because I have too much reading and learning going on already on different subjects and I cannot spend on this subject too much time (yet). Is that too hard for you to understand? I know what you're talking about, but there are a lot of PDFs out there my friend and you can't read them all from first page to the last :)

Comment: Set priorities. Image processing is a complex subject. I agree with @woodchips that you cannot sufficiently learn about FFTs by just getting snippets from the internet. Sooner or later, you will run into issues you do not understand because you are using code you don't understand. Then you will ask more questions here which we can't understand. If you have too much on your agenda this semester, don't put image processing on it as well.

Comment: @jjepsuomi - Yes, but if you admit there are a LOT of things to read, then how do you expect us to cover it all in one simple answer? All that will happen is you will get a small piece of the puzzle, then ask many questions in the comments to clear up your misunderstandings, and it will turn into a long term project for us to write what you could have read in the first place! (I see this happen over and over again.) It is time to start learning for you! Stop being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically outlined the right approach which I'll summarize here:

1) Do the 2D FFTs.

2) Multiply them by a weighting factor.  If you're FFTs are in (Real, Imaginary) form, multiply both components by the weight, and if (Magnitude, phase) just multiple the magnitude.  If you're interested in just high and low frequencies, this will likely be radial weights, giving weights to things depending on their frequency.

3) Add the two together.

4) Inverse 2D FFT.

You can do the addition (item 3), either before or after the iFFT.  Also, as Paul R mentioned, you can do the 2D filtering in the spatial domain instead of the frequency domain.